# Is fury a negative status effect?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

The status effect "fury" seems to recharge my limit breaks at about double the normal speed. But I also saw that there are Items which will cure this effect.  Is fury a bad status effect?  Does it cause me to take more damage?

Comment: The main thing I need to know is whether I should welcome this effect or try and cure it asap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It reduces your Attack %, which represents your accuracy.

If you use magic, don't cure, or if your Attack % is high enough with it don't cure, otherwise cure.

EDIT:

Did some research, and it reduced magic and physical attack accuracy by 30%, so always heal, unless you need to build up your limit break, you can cause this status by using a Hyper.

Clarification: Fury builds up your limit meter faster by increasing the amount it raises by per 1 point of damage, it may also increase damage, however this is contested.
[Forum discussing it](http://uk.gamespot.com/ps/rpg/finalfantasy7/show_msgs.php?pid=197341&topic_id=m-1-45609840)

Comment: I would think you should cure (Esuna) if you use magic. Fury forces the character to do melee attacks.

Comment: or tranquilizers :?

Comment: @briankb oh, I didn't know that.

Comment: Fury increases the limit gauge? You had to take damage to charge limits iirc

Comment: Briankb, you're thinking of berserk. Berserk status causes the affected character to attack as soon as their time bar is full, until the status is removed. Fury, as the answer says, decreases the affected character's accuracy, causing them to miss and as far as I know, causes the player to receive more damage when they are hit - which in turn causes the limit meter to rise faster than normal.

Comment: Fury does not force melee in FF7. I frequently induce this effect while trying to quickly obtain the team's limit breaks (achieved by repeatitive use of limit breaks).

Answer (score 1):

Wow many wrong answers here, the mechanics are simple.

Fury will decrease hit % by 30%.  Later in the game fury will not be noticeble as will nearly always hit even with it on the reason for this is you can have hit% well over 100% meaning a 30% reduction will be way above 70% and in many cases still over 100%, early game its very noticeable.  Fury the positive effect is it doubles the charging rate of the limit guage which is very useful, you do not deal or take extra damage with fury.

sadness the opposite effect will decrease damage you take by 30% as a positive effect, but it will also halve the rate the limit gauge increases.  the halving is not due to the damage reduction its due to been halved in real terms, so when factoring in the less damage taken the reduction is effectively about 65%.

Both effects have their usefulness, and I consider neither a negative effect, I use them both strategically during the course of the game.